# Set VAR on click and alert the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can't I get this to work??

I want to get the index() from the menu, and alert() the value when the hash changes, which it does.

The alert doesn't appear.

```
    $('#menu li a').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).parent().index()+1;
    });



    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () { //detect hash change
        var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1); //hash to string (= "myanchor")
        alert(index);
    });
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: By using `var`, you are making `index` local to the `click` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scoping issue, the `index` variable is local to the function it's declared in, so you can't access it from the other function.  Move the declaration to the outer scope and it will work:

```
var index;  // declare the variable
$('#menu li a').click(function() {
    // Assign the value, notice the `var` keyword isn't there anymore
    index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() { //detect hash change
    var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1); //hash to string (= "myanchor")
    // Get the value
    alert(index);
});
```

I suggest reading up on how scoping works in JavaScript - [JS Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#scopes) has a decent overview.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `index` is not in the same scope as the call to `alert`.

You may declare it as a global variable before both functions:

```
var index;
```

And then remove the `var` keyword in the first function:

```
$('#menu li a').click(function() {
    index = $(this).parent().index()+1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var index;
    $('#menu li a').click(function() {
        index = $(this).parent().index()+1;
    });



    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () { //detect hash change
        var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1); //hash to string (= "myanchor")
        alert(index);
    });
```